# IPv6 in a Small Business

Tags: ipv6, windows-sbs-2008, voip, small-business, windows-sbs

I’ve been tasked to identify a new server and IT equipment for the company I work for (employees <20). I’m looking at getting a SBS 2011 Standard box.

My Question is:

Apart from ensuring that our router is IPv6 compliant, is there anything else I need to do/investigate to ensure that we won’t have IPv6 related problems in the future?

When investigating this I can only find references to DNS Mangers etc. The SBS 2011 box will be used for exchange and remote log in access – it won’t be hosting any websites.
Also will VOIP phone systems be affected by IPv6? (We are running a rather old VOIP system, would that need to be updated?

Comment: You know I still don't know of any business that runs ipv6 for their LANs except some ISP's.  And even then it's run side by side with ipv4

Comment: @matt, that may be right today, but should they buy a new box in a few years, if the ISP decides to use IPv6 on WAN?

Comment: Even if your ISP decides to pop up IPv6 on their networks, they will - at the very least - provide a IPv4-to-IPv6 translation mechanism for you. After it is a business process, and with the ton of legacy networks that their customer base are using, it is detrimental for them to roll out 100% IPv6 connectivity to everyone without the risk of getting the wrath of frustrated customers.

So don't worry about it. You are doing fine.

Answer (score 2):

You will very probably run IPv4 and IPv6 side by side. IPv6 has advantages for i.e. VPN tunnels. If you use unique IPv6 addresses (or almost-always unique addresses like ULA) then you won't have conflicts like with RFC1918. The more applications and services that support IPv6 the more benefit you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it all.

Your routers, your SBS 2011 server.  All your workstations will be IPv6 enabled.

The only other thing I can think of is any network attached printers.  And if they do not have IPv6 you could either plug them into your SBS server (or another workstation) or use IPv4 connectivity (which you will likely being doing for a long time anyways).